# Always show same size tags for Tag Cloud in Wordpress Admin

Tags: wp-admin, tags

I wanted to know if there was a way to modify the back-end of Wordpress to do 2 things:

- Make all tags' font the same size, so none are larger than the others
- Always show the most used tags when creating/editing a post

This only applies to the back-end of Wordpress, not calling the tag cloud or any sort of front-end CSS that would be found in the theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this at functions.php

```
    /* Tagcloud, change the font size */
function custom_tag_cloud_widget($args) {
    $args['largest'] = 13; //largest tag
    $args['smallest'] = 13; //smallest tag
    $args['unit'] = 'px'; //tag font unit
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'custom_tag_cloud_widget' );
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a simpler solution:

Install the plugin **Add Admin CSS**

Go to Settings and put this code:

```
p#tagcloud-post_tag.the-tagcloud a {
  font-size: 1em!important; 
}
```

I put `1em` but feel free to put whatever value you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

With `wp_tag_cloud` you can set the `smallest` and `largest` argument to the same value:

```
$args = array(
    'smallest'                  => 8, 
    'largest'                   => 8,
);
echo wp_tag_cloud($args);
```

Unfortunately, that would require hacking the Core. Also, unfortunately, I don't see a filter that will allow you to alter those argument directly, so you are going to have to do this a bit brute-force-y.

```
add_action(
  'load-edit-tags.php',
  function () {
    add_filter(
      'wp_generate_tag_cloud',
      function ($return) {
        $pat = '|font-size: [0-9]+([^;]+)|';
        return preg_replace($pat,'8$1',$return);
      },
      1,2
    );
  }
);
```

Hooking to `load-edit-tags.php` should cause this to operate only on the `wp-admin/edit-tags.php` page on the backend, which is what I assume you want.
Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud